# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages (package does not contain a release)

Tags: php, github, composer-php

Why does `composer update` fail here?

```
$ composer update
 ...
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - The requested package _somePackage_ could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

    Potential causes:
     - A typo in the package name
     - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
       see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

    Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

$ cat composer.json 
{
  "name": "phpClasses.org-cwordstoNumbers/cwordstoNumbers",
  "type": "behat-extension",
  "description": "Convert English words (e.g., first, fifth, five hundred and seventieth) to numbers",
  "keywords": ["words to numbers", "cardinal", "ordinal"],
  "homepage": "https://www.phpclasses.org/package/10082-PHP-Convert-text-with-an-amount-to-its-numeric-value.html",
  "license": "GPL-3",
  "authors": [
     {
       "name": "Mohammed Asad",
       "email": "asadgenx@github.com"
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A composer package must contain at least one release.  If there are no releases, [add one](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/).